# removeChild sometimes removes entire span and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, removechild

I'm working on a rich text editor for iOS and have most of it working but running into endless problems ensuring that the cursor is visible in the viewport when the user starts typing.

I came up with a novel approach: insert a span at the cursor position, scroll to the span, and then remove it. (I haven't gotten to only scrolling if the span is on-screen.) Here's what I wrote:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {            
   jumpToID();
}, false);

function jumpToID() {
  var id = "jumphere2374657";
  var text = "<span id='" + id + "'>&nbsp;</span>"
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, text);
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.scrollIntoView();
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

In some cases this works just fine and in some cases it leaves a non-break space between every key press, removing the <span></span> tags only. Any ideas? I'm open to better ways of doing this if someone has suggestions. I'm a little shocked at how hard it is to make the cursor appear but then JS is new to me.

**EDIT**

This is the code that works:

```
var viewportHeight = 0;

function setViewportHeight(vph) {
  viewportHeight = vph;
  if(viewportHeight == 0 && vph != 0)
    viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
}

function getViewportHeight() {
  if(viewportHeight == 0)
    return window.innerHeight;
  return viewportHeight;
}

function makeCursorVisible() {
  var sel = document.getSelection();                  // change the selection
  var ran = sel.getRangeAt(0);                        // into a range
  var rec = ran.getClientRects()[0];                  // that we can get coordinates from
  if (rec == null) {
    // Can't get coords at start of blank line, so we
    // insert a char at the cursor, get the coords of that,
    // then delete it again. Happens too fast to see.
    ran.insertNode( document.createTextNode(".") );
    rec = ran.getClientRects()[0];  // try again now that there's text
    ran.deleteContents();
  }
  var top = rec.top;               // Y coord of selection top edge
  var bottom  = rec.bottom;        // Y coord of selection bottom edge
  var vph = getViewportHeight();
  if (top < 0)      // if selection top edge is above viewport top,
    window.scrollBy(0, top);  // scroll up by enough to make the selection top visible
  if (bottom >= vph)   // if selection bottom edge is below viewport bottom,
    window.scrollBy(0, bottom-vph + 1); // scroll down by enough to make the selection bottom visible
}
```

The viewportHeight is more complicated than need be for a web app. For a mobile app we need to account for the keyboard so offer a method for setting the viewportHeight manually as well as the automatic setting from the window.innerHeight.

Comment: Rather than using `removeChild`, what does `.execCommand('undo', ..` do?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried that. It doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm seeing something here. On contentEditable it creates a <div></div> tag around each row, so this happens:
<div>Line 1</div><div><br>/div><div>Line 2</div>

If I force Line 1<br>Line 2 and edit in there, it doesn't do this but if I enter it within the divs it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will work on iOS, but if the position of the cursor means that there is a Selection at that point..

```
function moveToSelection(){
    var sel = document.getSelection(), // change the selection
        ran = sel.getRangeAt(0),       // into a range
        rec = ran.getClientRects()[0], // that we can get co-ordinates from
        dy  = rec.top;                 // distance to move down/up
    window.scrollBy( 0, dy );          // actual move

    // console.log( sel, ran, rec, y );   // help debug
}

moveToSelection();
```

Relevant links

1. [**getSelection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getSelection)
2. [**getRangeAt**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection/getRangeAt)
3. [**getClientRects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getClientRects)
4. [**scrollBy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollBy)

Comment: That's quite close, it seems. I'm getting an undefined error for rec, though, if I type a key directly after a newline. This means the cursor is within a '<div><br><div>' and I assume can't form a rect if there is no text. Any suggestions how to adjust for that instance? Also, if you have any ideas how to not scroll if the cursor is already in the viewport I'd appreciate that, too. Currently it automatically goes to the top even if the cursor was already within the viewport. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: For not scrolling, check if `dy` is less than the viewport's height. As for undefined, find out the value of the range in this case, add a check for it and either ignore that case or do a different action (such as scrolling to the last `<br>`

Comment: Thanks @shhac! We got it working. I'll post the final code later as we have a few things to clean up first.

Comment: Hmm this is definitely working but I don't quite understand how the rec.top represents the dy?

Comment: @KevinLee https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRectReadOnly/top the support table at the bottom doesn't reflect the support of above code as the mdn page is specific to a section of the prototype tree which doesn't necessarily match up, but has crossover implementation