# How do I keep a textarea's caret always within the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a page with a very long textarea used for editing large amounts of texts. Normally, as you type, when the caret approaches the bottom of the textarea, the page will automatically scroll to keep the caret always within the viewport (Firefox will scroll by a single line at a time, Chrome will scroll the caret into the center of the viewport).

My problem comes from the fact that I am programmatically changing the contents of the text area based on what the user types. In some cases this involves adding extra content, thus pushing the caret out of view.

As soon as the user hits a key, the autoscroll kicks in and the caret is scrolled into view -- but not before, so as the user is typing they lose sight of the caret. I had hoped I could simply trigger key events on the textarea for the browser to autoscroll, but triggered events don't fully emulate user behavior and I do not get a response.

The only solution I can see now is to try to get the XY coordinates of the caret by:

1. Finding the character position of the caret.
2. Building a div that mirrors the content of the textarea with a marker at the caret position.
3. Measuring the position of the marker.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12738472/1615483

Answer (score 1):

I hate to suggest adding a whole library for one problem, but consider looking at CodeMirror. It handles all such stuff for you, and is fairly simple to use.

http://codemirror.net/

Answer (score 0):

[The previous solution was not compatible with Chrome (WebKit?)]

IF, a BIG if, the extra content is appended to the end of the input, the exercise below may offer the solution:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function btnGoOnClick(ctrl)
      {
        //-- For this POC the text content is reset to 160 lines of dummy text -
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        ctrl.value = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < 160; ++i)
        {
          ctrl.value += "dummy!\n";
        }

        //-- Then the carret is set to the last position -----------------------
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        if (ctrl.createTextRange)
        {
          //-- IE specific methods to move the carret to the last position

          var textRange = ctrl.createTextRange();
          textRange.moveStart("character", ctrl.value.length);
          textRange.moveEnd("character", 0);
          textRange.select();
        }
        else
        {
          //-- Mozilla and WebKit methods to move the carret

          ctrl.setSelectionRange(ctrl.value.length, ctrl.value.length);
        }

        //-- For WebKit, the scroll bar has to be explicitly set ---------------
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        ctrl.scrollTop = ctrl.scrollHeight;

        //-- Almost there: make sure the control has fucos and is into view ----
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        ctrl.focus();
        ctrl.scrollIntoView(false);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form">
      <input type="button" name="btnGo" value="Go!" onClick="btnGoOnClick(document.form.text);" />
      <div style="height: 1000px"></div>
      <textarea name="text" rows="80"></textarea>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I'm seeing is that scrollIntoView() scrolls the viewport to the top of the textarea, but that doesn't have any correlation with the position of the caret (my textarea's height is greater than the viewport height, so the caret can still be out of sight).

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I tested it against Mozilla and IE, skipping Chrome (WebKit). I devised a broader, fail proof, solution and am going to edit my post. Please, even if you already had your needs fulfilled, evaluate and, if proven right, mark my post as valid. I (we) need those credits :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already are on the javascript path and suppose a dynamic textarea height would pose a design issue, you could try autoresizing your textarea by content:

```
function resizeTextarea(textarea) {
  var lines = textarea.value.split('\n');
  var width = textarea.cols;
  var height = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var linelength = lines[i].length;
    if (linelength >= width) {
      height += Math.ceil(linelength / width);
    }
  }
  height += lines.length;
  textarea.rows = height;
}
```

I know this does not answer the specifics outlined in your post but it provides an alternative approach fitting your question title. So even if it's not useful for you, it may be just that for others visiting this question.

I personally hate too small text areas and dependin on the case, would prefer them autosizing.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, I suppose this is a solution to a different problem. In my case I was already auto-expanding the size of the textarea (though its default size was already larger than the view port) using jquery-elastic, which I believe does the same as the code you've provided.